# using methods arguments and this.data best practice

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Wondering which is the best practice between passing arguments in vue methods and using data or props reference with this.localData ?

Having a template like so

```js
            <div @click="close_tab"/>
              <span>
                {{ tabInstance.count }}
              </span>
            </div>
```

```js
        close_tab(id, isCurrentTab) {
            if (isCurrentTab) {
                this[REMOVE_CURRENT_TAB]();
                this.$router.push({ name: 'home' });
            } else {
                this[REMOVE_TAB](id);
            }
        },


// or below

        close_tab() {
            if (this.isCurrentTab) {
                this[REMOVE_CURRENT_TAB]();
                this.$router.push({ name: 'home' });
            } else {
                this[REMOVE_TAB](this.tab.id);
            }
        },
```

Comment: Without context it's hard to say

Comment: tks for your reply, can I help you with specific details ? I was just wondering if I should use this or pass arguments when I write methods :)

Comment: Where are you calling this method?

Comment: calling it on a template, object is not dynamic, edited the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your usage context. if you don't want to use `close_tab` with different values other than `this.tab.id` and `this.isCurrentTab` then you shouldn't write your method in parameters style.